# Codeigniter list_tables() from a database in a dropdown

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to know how to list the tables names from a database in a dropdown in CodeIgniter. I tried using `$this->db->list_tables()` and use it in a model just like when I want to populate dropdown with values from a table.

Controller:

```
$data['tables'] = $this->model->get_tables();
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="tabel">Data</label>
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <?php $attributes = 'class="form-control" id="tabel"';
   echo form_dropdown('tabel', $tables, set_value('tables'), $attributes);?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
function get_tables(){
  $result = $this->db->list_tables();

  $tablelist = array('- Table Lists -');

  foreach($result as $row) {
    return $tables = array($tablelist, $row);
  }
}
```

it returns just the first table [analisis] and the value set to 1 in the dropdown [checked it at the inspect element window].

[image: printscreen.png]

If I changed it to:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo $row;        
}
```

it returns array of tables [analisistable1table2] on top of the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

**[$this->db->list_tables()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/table_data.html)**

> Returns an array containing the names of all the tables in the
>   database you are currently connected

So no need of fetch result. Just comment this line of code

```
 $result= $this->db->list_tables();
 //$result = $query->result();// comment no need of it
```

Comment: It returns an array of table names on top of the webpage, but the form_dropdown is empty. Even if I don't  call / echo it in the view, just put `$data['tables'] -> $this->model->get_tables();` , the tables name list is there. Like table1table2table3... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    return $tables = array($tablelist, $row);
}
```

Because of return, the foreach block above only iterates once, so the contents of `$tables` are only `$tablelist` and the first element of `$result`.
Why don't you just return the `$this->db->list_tables()` like this

```
function get_tables(){
   return $this->db->list_tables();
}
```